# How to load features and label from dataframe in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use keras with tensorflow to train a network. I've my own digit dataset of Myanmar language. I'm trying to develop Myanmar digits recognition using neural network using python. I've train.csv file and test.csv file which have a header with format label,pixel0,...,pixel783. I used pandas to load dataframe. But I want to split the dataframe into features and labels.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("mmdigitstrain.csv")
dataframe2 = pd.read_csv("mmdigitstest.csv")

(X_train, y_train) = splitfeaturesandlabelfromdataframe
(X_test, y_test) = splitfeaturesandlabelfromdataframe2
```

Comment: please provide the name of the label column in your dataframe

Comment: the name of the label column is label.

Comment: add a snippet of your data in the csv files

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If your dataframe contains last column as the `label` column. Then use the following</strike>

<strike>`X_train = dataframe.iloc[:,:-1]
Y_train = dataframe.iloc[:,-1:]`</strike>

```
X_train = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.columns != 'label']
Y_train = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.columns == 'label']
```

Updated according to the comment below. Now subsetting dataframe w.r.t to column name `label`

The other way is to combine/ merge the two dataframes, and try to use [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: label column is the first column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the datas on numpy arrays

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_train = pd.read_csv("mmdigitstrain.csv")
df_test = pd.read_csv("mmdigitstest.csv")

y_train=df_train['label'].to_numpy() 
#check the shape should bd nbofitem x 1 in train dataset
print(y_train.shape)
X_train=df_train.drop(columns=['label']).to_numpy()
check the shape should bd nbofitem x  780 in train dataset
print(X_train.shape)

y_test=df_test['label'].to_numpy() 
#check the shape should bd nbofitem x 1 in test dataset
print(y_test.shape)
X_test=df_test.drop(columns=['label']).to_numpy()
check the shape should bd nbofitem x  780 in test dataset
print(X_test.shape)
```